# Techniques to measure/picture very low (cryo) temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, metrology, low-temperature-physics

I am looking for an experimental technique to measure/create a temperature map of a small object (few mm diameter), like in terms of IR camera.

However, all IR-cameras I encountered measured temperatures higher than -20 C, and I would need something around 10K. (With 10K I mean the temperature of the object, not of the camera, as I am aware that some of the IR cameras are cryo-cooled).
Are there any IR camera which can do it/ are there any other techniques to perform my task?
If not, how low one could still get with existing techniques?